# Windows is saying access denied to files I own

Tags: windows, windows-8, permissions, git

So, recently Windows has decided to do some trolling on me and make it impossible to commit to my git repository

It gives me this error in git (in Cygwin):

```
$ git commit -a
error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database .git/objects

error: NVG510Fixer/NVG510Fixer/Resources/layout/WarningConfirmation.axml: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file NVG510Fixer/NVG510Fixer/Resources/layout/WarningConfirmation.axml
fatal: updating files failed
```

Well... but then I go to the NVG510Fixer folder and recursively take ownership of everything in there and make sure that *Everyone* has full control. This seems to work, but it doesn't make the error go away.. So, I decide to go to `.git` and right click on properties and take ownership(recursively) from there. At this point, it gets even more weird:

[image]

What the hell is Windows doing?! I'm an Administrator. This computer isn't even joined to a domain. How can I not access files that I could access just a few minutes ago!?

Comment: Are you sure that the Cygwin prompt is opened with Admin access ?

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`takeown`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753024.aspx) command from a administrative command line. It is possible to remove `Full Access` permissions to the Administrators group, if that happens the GUI version can't change permissions but the command-line command can still do it.

```
takeown /f C:\dev\nvg510controls\.git /r /d Y
```

if you want to be extra fancy you can set the permissions [via the command line](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753525.aspx) too

```
icacls C:\dev\nvg510controls\.git /t /grant Everyone:(F)
```

If neither of those commands work download [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) and do the command

```
psexec -i -s icacls C:\dev\nvg510controls\.git /t /grant Everyone:(F)
```

that will run `icacls` as the SYSTEM user instead of the Administrator user.

Comment: Tried this for a similar situation and "Error:Access is denied"

Comment: @John then you where not running it from a administrative command line. You need to make sure you choose "Run As Administrator" when you opened the command prompt.

Comment: I get Access is denied as well, and I'm definitely in an administrator command prompt.

Comment: @JasonSouthwell In that situation it is likely that the file is protected in a way that only the SYSTEM user can modify it. In that situation use [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pxexec.aspx) and do the command `psexec -i -s icacls C:\dev\nvg510controls\.git /t /grant Everyone:(F)` that will run `icacls` as the SYSTEM user.

Comment: I had tried that and saw nothing.  I did figure it out though. in my case, it was that the folder was still open in a Windows 10 Anniversary Edition bash shell somewhere on my desktop.  Apparently when git tried to remove the folder, it was still open there and put the folder in some limbo state.  cd'ing out of the folder in bash automatically made the folder disappear.  Odd I didn't see bash as holding a lock on that folder though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's going to help anyone out but I'll note here that I've just had a problem with Git not having permission to access files and tried the answer above with no success.

The problem turned out to be that, on a fairly new server, an enterprise virus checker saw a lot of activity in the .git directory from the Git process, marked Git as a suspicious process and stopped allowing it to access any files.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the owner back to someone else and back to yourself recursively. That generally does the trick for me. I think this might be because you don't have access to the sub folders and files, but only the .git folder. Change the owner and select all subfolders option. Then change the permissions with the same tree option enabled
see if it works

Comment: This likely should have been a comment since you didn't explain HOW to change the owner to another user.